# Change a string based on array length

Tags: javascript

I have this string:

```
url = `/cliente/porsegmento?idsSegmentN1=${segmentId}`;
```

and `segmentId` is an array. What I need to do is change the url if the array length is > 1.

Here's an example:
`segmentId`length = 2.
The string shoud look like:

```
url = `/cliente/porsegmento?idsSegmentN1=${segmentId-INDEXONE}&idsSegmentN1=${segmentId-INDEX2}`;
```

if `segmentId` length = 3:

```
url = `/cliente/porsegmento?idsSegmentN1=${segmentId-INDEXONE}&idsSegmentN1=${segmentId-INDEX2}&idsSegmentN1=${segmentId-INDEX3}`;
```

But now I have no idea how to do it. Can someone help me, please?

Edit:
`segmentId-INDEX3` is supposed to be the array value.

Comment: What is `INDEXONE`, `INDEX2` etc?

Comment: It is supposed to be the array value @sabbir.alam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate the query params using a for loop.

```
let baseUrl = '/cliente/porsegmento';
let queryParams = '?';
for(let i =0;i<segmentId.length; i++) {
    if(i>0) {  queryParams += '&'; }
    queryParams = `${queryParams}idsSegmentN1=${segmentId[i]}`;
}
url = baseUrl + queryParams;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```js
const baseUrl = '/cliente/porsegmento';
const segmentId = ['1', '2', '3'];
 const params = segmentId.map((segment, index) => `idsSegmentN${index}=${segment}`).join('&');
 const finalUrl = `${baseUrl}${(segmentId.length > 0) ? `?${params}`: ''}`;
 console.log('finalUrl: ', finalUrl);
```

Comment: Hey, your code also works but since sabbir answered first I had to accept his answer. Thanks anyway!!

Comment: actually, Greedo answered first but that's ok

Answer (score 1):

You need to add loop on the array:

```js
function generateURL(segmentId) {
  let url = '/cliente/porsegmento?';
  if (Array.isArray(segmentId)) {
    segmentId.forEach((sid, i) => { url += `idsSegmentN1=${sid}${i < segmentId.length - 1 ? '&' : ''}`; });

  } else {
    url += `idsSegmentN1=${segmentId}`;
  }
  return url;
}

// case single value
console.log(generateURL(1))

// case array
console.log(generateURL([1,2,3,4]))
```

Comment: Hey, your code also works but since sabbir answered first I had to accept his answer. Thanks anyway!!